# MySql Web Configuration Tool Error in VS 2012

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012

When I press the button for MySql Web Configuration in Visual Studio 2012 it immediately shows the following error.

This is in a basically blank web app MVC 4 - nothing added really and yet I can't get this thing to fire up - any ideas?

[image]

I

Answer (score 1):

your problem is located in a file called "machine.config", there are 2 files.

1st:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ [version_no] \Config
```

2nd:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\ [version_no] \Config
```

- backup each file before making any changes
- open each file with notepad
- search document for the following sections

> ```
> <membership>
> <profile>
> <roleManager>
> ```

within these sections, remove everything after MySql.Web and stop before the closing end quote... it should like this when your down  ---> MySql.Web"

- same and repeat for the next machine.config file
- close Visual Studio
- reopen your project and try the website configuration tool.

not sure why this works. just know how to fix it.